# CSV data comparison Linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv, debian

I am new to Linux and I try to manipulate some data in a bash file. I tried many solutions without any success. I have three conditions that made me lose myself into too many commands:

1. Compare if the xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (column 3) is already present in the file
2. If it have been found, compare the time (column 1) from all lines that contains the same xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
3. If the time is same, compare the signal strength (column 2) and send back the line with the lowest value.

Data file (csv):

```
Mar 6 2014 17h29h43, -55, xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (This line has to be removed)
Mar 6 2014 17h29h43, -38, xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Mar 6 2014 17h29h44, -60, yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
```

Wished result:

```
Mar 6 2014 17h29h43, -38, xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (=> lowest value for xx:xx:xx:xx 17h29h43)
Mar 6 2014 17h29h44, -60, yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide the solution/code that you tried and tell us what went wrong with it. That way you'll find better answers and help.

Comment: Is there a reason why this must be done in bash?  You should probably use awk or perl to do this type of processing.

Comment: See whether [`csvfix`](https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) can help; it is an extremely powerful tool for manipulating CSV files.  Alternatively, this looks like a job for `awk`.

Comment: I wrote a hole script to get those data and i did it with bash. So I assumed I would do it in the rest of the script. There is no other specific reason. I'm gonna have a deeper look at csvfix. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should do this in perl/python but i was bored so why not:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename=$1

#read input file and store into associative array
declare -A arr
while IFS=',' read date value string ; do
    #Change time from 10h00h00 to 10:00:00
    dt=$(sed s'/\([0-9]\+\)h/\1:/g' <<< "$date")
    #Get rid of leading spaces
    string=$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$string")
    value=$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$value")
    #Convert datetime to unix epoch
    epoch=$(date --date="$dt" +%s)
    #echo "$epoch,$string"

    #Create unique key for array
    key="$epoch,$string"

    #Check if key already exists if so compare
    #values and keep the highest    
    ov=-10000
    [ ${arr["$key"]+abc} ] && ov=${arr["$key"]}

    if [[ "$value" -gt "$ov" ]]; then 
        arr["$key"]="$value"
    fi
done < "$filename"

#Display output, sort on epoch and then remove from output
for i in ${!arr[@]}; do
    #Split key into epoch and string
    epoch=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<< $i)
    string=$(awk -F, '{print $2}' <<< $i)

    #Convert date back to long format
    dt=$(date -d@"$epoch" '+%h %-d %Y %Hh%Mh%S')

    echo "$epoch $dt, ${arr[$i]} $string"
done | sort -h | sed 's/^[0-9]\+ //'
```

Input file (datafile):

```
Mar 6 2014 17h29h43, -55, xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Mar 6 2014 17h29h43, -38, xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Mar 6 2014 17h29h44, -60, yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
Mar 9 2014 07h29h44, -6, 11:22:33:44:55
Mar 9 2014 07h29h44,  6, 22:33:44:55:66
Mar 9 2014 07h29h44,  3, 22:33:44:55:66
Mar 1 2014 14h33h04, -60, anythingreally
```

Output:

```
Mar 1 2014 14h33h04, -60 anythingreally
Mar 6 2014 17h29h43, -38 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Mar 6 2014 17h29h44, -60 yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
Mar 9 2014 07h29h44, -6 11:22:33:44:55
Mar 9 2014 07h29h44, 6 22:33:44:55:66
```